# Vite's optimizeDeps.include doesn't work with relative paths

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

In my Vite/Vue3 project I have a file in `<project dir>/dist/foobar.js`. Following paths in `<project dir>/vite.config.js` won't work:

```
optimizeDeps: {
      include: [
        '/dist/foobar.js', // returns "Failed to resolve dependency"
        './dist/foobar.js', // returns "Failed to resolve dependency"
        './../dist/foobar.js', // returns "Failed to resolve dependency"
        'dist/foobar.js' // only this works
      ],
    },
```

Only `dist/foobar.js` works but I cannot use `dist/foobar.js` as a path to import this file, because if I add to App.vue:

```
import * as test from 'dist/test.js'
```

it throws an error: `The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved: dist/hmr-test.umd.js`

Only after I add a `dist` alias that points to `./dist` (or `./../dist`) the import and `optimizeDeps.include` will both work at the same time, but I don't want to use an alias. I'd rather make `optimizeDeps.include` accept relative paths, is it possible?